# Using hex characters as input to a c program changes the characters?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, hex

I have a short c program called "hex" that takes two characters and outputs their corresponding hex code:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char var[3];
    printf("Enter two hex characters: ");
    scanf("%2s", var);
    printf("%x ", var[0]);
    printf("%x ", var[1]);

}
```

Now when I call this program with an input consisting of the two characters "A" and "0" in hex code:

```
echo -e "\x41\x00" | ./hex
```

Then the output is (as expected) "41 0".
But when I call this program two times with the hex code "0d":

```
echo -e "\x0d\x0d" ./hex
```

Then the output is "0 bb" ?
Why is it like that? What can I do to use the correct input for the hex code "0d"s instead of what I'm using?

EDIT: 
The scanf should be before the print statements, that was a copy paste error. I corrected it.

Comment: I got output `A ./hex` from `echo -e "\x41\x00" ./hex`. Shouldn't it be `echo -e "\x41\x00" | ./hex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printings must be after reading.

Also `%s` will skip newline characters and `\x0d` is CR, which is one of newline characters, so you should use `fread()` to avoid the input being skipped.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char var[3];
    fread(var, 1, 2, stdin);
    printf("%x ", var[0]);
    printf("%x ", var[1]);
    printf("Enter two hex characters: ");
}
```

Comment: What if I cant change the input method (scanf)? Is there any way to let it take the newline character as input or is it impossible?

Comment: You can use `%c` like `scanf("%2c", var);`

Answer (score 0):

your code is one big ***Undefined Behaviour***. You print elements of the uninitialised array. After printing you *`scanf`* those elements.

Don't you think that the order is a bit weird?